# angularjs ng-form and ng-repeat with input validation and submit action

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-form

Angular 1.6.2

Try to iterate over elements of collection inputted by user and then check their validity and enable submit action if validation passes.

I try to use `ng-form` for this purpose and have two approach but each of them has side-effect.

First approach (`ng-form` at the table level):

```
<table class="datatable table table-stripped table-responsive" ng-form="form">
    <thead>
    <tr class="headers">
        <th ng-repeat="header in ctrl.headers">{{header}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="linkDelay in ctrl.currentLinkDelays">
        <td>{{linkDelay.label}}</td>
        <td>{{linkDelay.value}}</td>
        <td id="proposed-ld-input-column" width=40%>
            <input id="proposed-ld-input" name="input"
                   class="form-control ng-invalid-min ng-invalid-max ng-invalid-required"
                   type="number" ng-model="ctrl.inputs[linkDelay.property]"
                   data-ng-required="true" min="0" max="180"/>
            <div class="error" data-ng-show="form.input.$error.required">
                Message required
            </div>
            <div class="error" data-ng-show="form.input.$error.max">
                Message max
            </div>
            <div class="error" data-ng-show="form.input.$error.min">
                Message min
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid"
        ng-click="ctrl.applyChanges()">
    <span>Apply</span>
</button>
```

In this approach submit is disabled until all input are in set ranges but validation messages don't appear.

Second approach (`ng-form` at the table column level):

```
<table class="datatable table table-stripped table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr class="headers">
        <th ng-repeat="header in ctrl.headers">{{header}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="linkDelay in ctrl.currentLinkDelays">
        <td>{{linkDelay.label}}</td>
        <td>{{linkDelay.value}}</td>
        <td id="proposed-ld-input-column" width=40% ng-form="form">
            <input id="proposed-ld-input" name="input"
                   class="form-control ng-invalid-min ng-invalid-max ng-invalid-required"
                   type="number" ng-model="ctrl.inputs[linkDelay.property]"
                   data-ng-required="true" min="0" max="180"/>
            <div class="error" data-ng-show="form.input.$error.required">
                Message required
            </div>
            <div class="error" data-ng-show="form.input.$error.max">
                Message max
            </div>
            <div class="error" data-ng-show="form.input.$error.min">
                Message min
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" 
        ng-click="ctrl.applyChanges()">
    <span>Apply</span>
</button>
```

In this approach validation messages appear but submit button is always enabled.

Could you tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the inputs different names:

```
<table class="datatable table table-stripped table-responsive" ng-form="form">
    <thead>
    <tr class="headers">
        <th ng-repeat="header in ctrl.headers">{{header}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="linkDelay in ctrl.currentLinkDelays">
        <td>{{linkDelay.label}}</td>
        <td>{{linkDelay.value}}</td>
        <td id="proposed-ld-input-column{{$index}}" width=40%>
            ̶<̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶d̶=̶"̶p̶r̶o̶p̶o̶s̶e̶d̶-̶l̶d̶-̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶"̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶=̶"̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶"̶
            <input id="proposed-ld-input{{$index}}" name="input{{$index}}"
                   class="form-control ng-invalid-min ng-invalid-max ng-invalid-required"
                   type="number" ng-model="ctrl.inputs[linkDelay.property]"
                   data-ng-required="true" min="0" max="180"/>
            <div class="error" ng-show="form['input'+$index].$error.required">
                Message required
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-show="form['input'+$index].$error.max">
                Message max
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-show="form['input'+$index].$error.min">
                Message min
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid"
        ng-click="ctrl.applyChanges()">
    <span>Apply</span>
</button>
```

The `ng-repeat` creates multiple inputs. They need to be assigned different names for the error messages to be correct.